# Hadoop Pig regular expression

Tags: regex, hadoop, split, apache-pig, items

My questions are related to Hadoop’s Pig regular expression functions.  In particular, I want to explore whether these functions may be used to parse a simple log line.  I am aware of the fact that I can get the desired output using Streams or Java functions and so please answer using Pig Latin only.

In order to demonstrate my concerns, I use a file called Log file log.txt.  It contained only a single line of text and was uploaded using the following command.

```
data = LOAD 'farzan/log.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
```

The line it contains is
dump data;

```
(Jul 17 10:59:59 domain.domain2.company.com <2012-07-17 10:59:59.605 UTC>:[133338908]:<MDS-CS_MDS2>:<DEBUG>:<LAYER = ABC, DEVICEPIN = 25e54h40, GMETAG = 1358096454, TAG = 80, METHOD = writeDisplayImageUpdate, RESULT = 0, SIZE = 30416, DETAIL = OUTGOING>)
```

SPLIT ITEMS SEPARATION ISSUE
Now let’s split data using regular expression

```
data_split = FOREACH data GENERATE STRSPLIT(line, ' <|[\\]>]:[\\[<]');
```

dump data_split;

```
((Jul 17 10:59:59 domain.domain2.company.com,2012-07-17 10:59:59.605 UTC,133338908,MDS-CS_MDS2,DEBUG,LAYER = ABC, DEVICEPIN = 25e54h40, GMETAG = 1358096454, TAG = 80, METHOD = writeDisplayImageUpdate, RESULT = 0, SIZE = 30416, DETAIL = OUTGOING>))
```

The result is correct but how do I separate each of the elements?

Comment: You have elements separated in array `data` - what else you need?

Answer (score 0):

Use FLATTEN:

```
data_split = FOREACH data GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, ' <|[\\]>]:[\\[<]'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I had used flatten but it only removes one of the pair of parentheses.  It still doesn't let me get each element found separately.

Comment: I think you do have each element separately, Pig just outputs tuples on the console with parentheses around them. If you use flatten and dump shows something like (field1, field2, ...), that means data_split is a bag of tuples with those fields. If you want to reference the fields by name, you have to use an AS clause after GENERATE.

If you mean "separate" as in a completely different tuple for each field, then you should be able to get that using something like "data_split_2 = FOREACH data_split GENERATE FLATTEN(*);"

Comment: Thanks for your response but it did not work for me.  When I tried: `grunt> describe data_split
data_split: {(null)}
` And your suggested code errors out. `data_split_2 = FOREACH data_split GENERATE FLATTEN(*);
2012-08-07 12:18:42,789 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " "*" "* "" at line 1, column 52.
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    "-" ...
    "(" ...
    "(" ...
    "(" ...
`